# Is it possible to get the property name from a data_path?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I can copy the data path of any property in the user interface with *Copy Data Path* which is `rigid_body.friction` in the example screenshot. Is there a way how to get the property name using the copied data path?

[image]

```
name = getPropertyNameFromDataPath("rigid_body.friction")
print(name) # needs to output "Friction"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank you to **@Karan** for directing me into the right path. I was able to come up with a general solution for any data path (Right click <kbd>RMB</kbd> any property in the user interface *> Copy Data Path*) and then use the function:

```
def get_property_name(data_path) -> str:
    s = data_path
    i = s.find('.')
    data_path_1 = ""
    data_path_2 = s
    if i > 0:
        ri = s.rindex('.')
        data_path_1 = '.' + s[0:ri]
        data_path_2 = s[ri+1:len(s)]
    data = eval("bpy.context.object" + data_path_1)
    return data.rna_type.properties[data_path_2].name if hasattr(data, data_path_2) else ''
```

Sample Outputs:

```
print(get_property_name('rotation_euler'))
print(get_property_name('rigid_body.collision_shape'))
print(get_property_name('modifiers["Bevel"].width'))
print(get_property_name('modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.surface_distance'))

# outputs:
#
# Eurler Rotation
# Collision Shape
# Width
# Surface Emission
```

Comment: This will only work on the object's properties

Comment: @Karan it works perfectly even modifiers. i added some sample outputs, let me know if you find something that doesn't work :)

Comment: @Karan you're right it can only cater to objects and its modifiers. i still need to find a way to make it possible for node trees as well. maybe a hard-coded check for `node_tree.nodes` in `node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[5].default_value`

Comment: Why do you need such function?

Comment: so that i can auto add a driver to every field in the UI https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269433/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-driver-driven-by-a-new-property/269438#269438

Answer (score 4):

```py
import bpy


def get_property_name(data, property) -> str:
    ''' Get the name of a property.

    data (AnyType) - Data from which to take property.
    property (str) - Identifier of property in data.
    return (str) - The name of the property.
    '''
    return data.rna_type.properties[property].name if hasattr(data, property) else ''


name = get_property_name(bpy.context.object.rigid_body, 'friction')

print(name)
```

Comment: it works for friction. but is it possible for a generalized function for all data paths? like it should also work for `modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.surface_distance` or any other property that you right click and Copy Data Path

Comment: Yes, it will work on all properties. You have to give the `data` and `property` in this case `C.object.modifiers['Fluid'].flow_settings` is the data and `surface_distance` is the property.

Comment: It will not work from the copied data_path from the interface, you have to specify `data` and `property`

Comment: thanks so much for your code it helped me find a generalized solution! should i post a new answer or do you want me to edit your answer?

Comment: i posted the solution :) thank you so much!

Comment: It's sad though it only returns "Default Value" as the name for all the node tree fields,  any idea if there is a way to get node tree field names?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Full Data Path` instead of `Data Path`

```py
import bpy


def get_property_name_from_data_path(data_path) -> str:
    ''' Get the name of a property.

    data_path (str) - Data path from which to take data and property.
    return (str) - The name of the property.
    '''
    data = eval('.'.join(data_path.split('.')[:-1]))
    property = data_path.split('.')[-1]
    if property == 'default_value':
        return data.name

    return data.rna_type.properties[property].name if hasattr(data, property) else ''

name = get_property_name_from_data_path('bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[2].default_value')

print(name)
```

Comment: thank you very much! this will come in handy! :)