# How to get a shader node's field name using data path?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

In this post [Is it possible to get the property name from a data_path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269442/is-it-possible-to-get-the-property-name-from-a-data-path) I am able to get the field names from <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Copy Data Path* in all object properties as well as their modifier name fields using this code:

```
def get_property_name(data_path) -> str:
    s = data_path
    i = s.find('.')
    data_path_1 = ""
    data_path_2 = data_path
    if i > 0:
        ri = s.rindex('.')
        data_path_1 = '.' + s[0:ri]
        data_path_2 = s[ri+1:len(s)]
    data_block = "bpy.context.object"
    data = eval(data_block + data_path_1)
    return data.rna_type.properties[data_path_2].name if hasattr(data, data_path_2) else ''
```

Unfortunately if you change the line `data_block = "bpy.context.object"` with, for example the default material of the default cube named *Material* value to line `data_block = 'bpy.data.materials["Material"]'` and then call the function with any node field's data path, it will always return the same name **Default Value**. For example, the data path for the node field *Subsurface Radius* is `node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[2].default_value` and will return the name **Default Value** instead of **Subsurface Radius** as will all the other node fields. Is there any other way how we can retrieve the node field name?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method here will work for all node trees including Shader Nodes, Compositor Nodes, and Geometry Nodes.

```
material = bpy.data.materials['Material']
path = 'node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[2].default_value'
material.path_resolve(path, False).data.name  # => Subsurface Radius
```

Comment: excellent!! thank you soo much!

Comment: there are times i pass an incorrect path and `path_resolve` throws an error, is there some check i can make before calling this function? something like `if is_path_resolveable(): path_resolve()`?

Comment: Use a try and catch the error.

Comment: hmmm yeah but i tried to avoid that as it is expensive XD well if there's no other way, then i'll use a try/catch :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Full Data Path` instead of `Data Path`

```py
import bpy


def get_property_name_from_data_path(data_path) -> str:
    ''' Get the name of a property.

    data_path (str) - Data path from which to take data and property.
    return (str) - The name of the property.
    '''
    data = eval('.'.join(data_path.split('.')[:-1]))
    property = data_path.split('.')[-1]
    if property == 'default_value':
        return data.name

    return data.rna_type.properties[property].name if hasattr(data, property) else ''

name = get_property_name_from_data_path('bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[2].default_value')

print(name)
```

Comment: thank you. unfortunately, i can't use full data path because i'm depending on the keying_set feature. when i do *Add to Keying Set* it will only put the relative path. So i only have that value to deal with.

Comment: Ok, but this will work on every property.

Comment: but yeah this is also really cool it can get the name for every property for all node trees! great job and thank you very much!